# Run and set the validation errors on one field based on the value of other field in angular form builder/group

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I want custom function validator to run on blur of both StartDate and EndDate

component.ts

```
Createform(){
this.studentForm = formBuilder.group({
      StartDate: ['', Validators.required, customFunction(), updateOn: "blur" ],
      EndDate: ['', null,customFunction(), updateOn: "blur" ],

}
```

Custom Function

```
customFunction(){
 if (EndDate <= startDate) {
          return of({ invalidDate: true });
        } 
      }  
      return of(null);
    };
}
```

It sets the CreateForm.controls['StartDate'].errors?.invalidDate to true when run on StartDate. Is it possible to set this invalidDate on EndDate even if I run the function on StartDate?

Custom function run correctly but when it runs on StartDate, it sets the errors array on start date but I want the error to be set on EndDate, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom function, you can use setErrors function to set error on different field

Custom Function

```
customFunction(){
 if (EndDate <= startDate) {
         this.studentForm.form.controls['endDate'].setErrors({'invalidDate': true});;
        } 
      }  
      return of(null);
    };
}
```